# On Android in an adb shell, why does `find /` not find at least what `find a b` does?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm a bit puzzled about the way `find` behaves on an Android (axolotl) `adb` shell.

I wanted to find *all* `DCIM` folders and ran

```
find / -name DCIM
```

and got

```
/sdcard/DCIM
```

Remembering there was at least also `/storage/46G8-22GB` I ran

```
find /storage -name DCIM
```

and got

```
/storage/46G8-22GB/DCIM
```

Strange.

So I ran `find / ..` again and got `/storage/46G8-22GB/DCIM` now - different from what I got when I ran the exactly same command the the first time (!!).

Then I ran `find /sdcard ..` and got `/sdcard/DCIM`, and now `find /` gives me only `/sdcard/DCIM`

So the result of `find / -name DCIM` somehow depends on what I did in the past.

Why is this?

And how do I reliably get *all* folders?

Comment: Android heavily uses symbolic links for providing directories like `/storage`. Therefore I would recommend to add `-L` option to find. BTW: on my Pixel4 Android 12 the results of find are different. find on `/` does return nothing.

Comment: Well, I know that symlink kung-foo but that is not what my question was about: you run `find /` twice and get different results!